django-admin startproject coredj File "<stdin>", line 1 django-admin startproject core SyntaxError: invalid syntax what's problem here?
Whenever I am firing django-admin startproject core this command it throws me syntax error. I am using python version3.11 and django version in 5.0.6. I am trying to create this in my E:drive and I have successfully installed the django and import it look for the version created virtual env but still, not working throwing syntax error at startproject
django-admin startproject coredj
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    django-admin startproject coredj
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I checked for compatible version of django with python. when I run the command I expect it to create the foldername core in my pythonproject directory which is residing in my **E :\ ** but it's not happening

You're typing that command into a Python shell, not the system shell.

Thankyouh @AKX! that was really a silly mistake
